# How to determine the value of a string?

Tags: java, string, compare

Sorry for the stupid question, but I've never really understood how to determine the value of a string. For instance, which is greater, "shaft", or "scream" and what? What components should you look for when comparing?

Comment: Google is a great place to start.

Comment: Not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: In what aspect do you want to compare? You mean by size or content?

Comment: For an example, in a binary search tree, when adding nodes, what determines if shaft is "bigger" than scream?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are compared lexicographically

See this link for Java String compareTo

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

A String doesn't really have what you call a *value*. `String` implements `Comparable`. The [JavaDoc for `String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the **Unicode value** of each character in the strings. The character sequence represented by this String object is compared lexicographically to the character sequence represented by the argument string.

Answer (score 1):

See [String.compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29):

> Compares two strings lexicographically .. returning a value less than 0 if this string is lexicographically less than the string argument; and a value greater than 0 if this string is lexicographically greater than the string argument.

Where [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) means ordered "as found a dictionary".

Thus using `compareTo`:

```
"shaft".compareTo("scream")  // -> more than 0: "shaft comes after scream"
"scream".compareTo("shaft")  // -> less than 0: "scream comes before shaft"
```

Comment: @user201535 You're welcome. Since Java doesn't allow operator overloading, when dealing with object types (like String), any comparison methods (i.e. `equals`, `compareTo`) and information about them will be found in the appropriate class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally its alphabetical order for string comparisions

Answer (score 0):

A String's compareTo method compares the String's lexicographically.
[Java String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Compare character by character.

```
s  h  a  r  p     //sharp is greater. first non matching character is compared.

=  =  =  ^

s  h  a  f  t
```